# Linux distribution for beginners that does not need PPA repositories to install up to date software

Tags: linux, desktop-environment

On my Dad's older laptop, I had KUbuntu installed for him.

I had choosen the KDE desktop environment because I believed it was relatively easy to use for people coming from the Windows world.

BTW : If you know other desktop environments for beginners, please tell me.

I also had Launchpad PPAs repositories added for him to install up to date software.

But PPAs repos can become a mess and sometime discretely break python-packages without breaking debian packages dependencies (maybe because some packagers didn't update some dependencies correctly).

To sum things up I looking for a Linux distribution :

- for beginner
- with KDE (or other very easy desktop environment) easy to install (if not already installed)
- relatively up to date software without having to add PPAs repos
- with enough support from community for me to solve eventual pb.

So far, I came across MX Linux (I've never used it yet), Manjaro Linux (I've never used it yet) and Linux Mint (last resort because I don't to have to handle PPAs).

Can you help ?

Comment: Maybe you can find one here: [distrowatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/) They have a short description of each distro that is displayed when you click on the distro name in the "Page Hit Ranking" at the right of the page.

Comment: Always up-to-date software often comes at the cost of stability (which is why distributions like Ubuntu or Debian often have such "aged versions": they are tested to work well together). If that's a price you're willing to pay, watch out for distributions offering "rolling releases". As for "beginners coming from Windows", I often find [Zorin OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorin_OS) recommended. It's no "rolling release" distro though, and also based on Ubuntu.

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions) might help you find rolling release distros. Not sure which one would be suited for beginners, though; maybe Manjaro or PCLinux.

Comment: @Izzy Does this mean "rolling distributions" have more up to date software but come with the price of less stability ? But maybe, they're stable enough for beginners every needs, right ?

Comment: At least Manjaro seems to be that way. Rolling releases permanently update everything, so you won't have to manually update to a new release of the distro – that happens "on the path"; opposed to that, point-releases are more stable but do update applications only "at point level" – e.g. if they originally ship with Foobar 2.1.1, you won't get Foobar 3.* before updating the distro itself to its new version. So *chances* that something breaks are a bit higher with rolling releases, which doesn't mean they're "constantly breaking" ;) Manjaro seems quite stable. I haven't tried it myself, though.